# Do curl operation using java

Tags: java, php, post, curl, httpurlconnection

I have done a curl operation using php. This is my code.

```
$ch = curl_init($endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($username . ":" . $password)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonObjectFields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Now I need to rewrite this code in java. I am not much familler with HttpURLConnection in java. Can any body help?

Comment: Yes. Check out this link: [How to use java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: need to set above parameters to request. How to set?

Comment: Why this holds? Those answers does not provide solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use HttpURLConnection

```
HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL("myurl").openConnection()));
myConnection.setDoOutput(true);
myConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
myConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
myConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
myConnection.connect();

String jsonData = "{'foo' : 'bar'}";
byte[] outputBytes = jsonData.getBytes("UTF-8");
OutputStream os = myConnection.getOutputStream();
os.write(outputBytes);
os.close();
```

I hope my answer is clear enough. If you have any question regarding my answer you can ask in the comment :)

Comment: how to set post feilds in this?  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonObjectFields); related to php

Comment: @manitaz you can set it in the jsonData string